# Flutter how to get a parent widget of unknown type

Tags: flutter, dart, tree, widget

I'm trying to improve error messages from a widget I'm writing.

if an error occurs I want to be able to dump out the widget tree to show the user the ancestors of my widget.

To do this I need to display the widget tree from my widget back up the tree towards the root.

The only way I've see to obtain a parent widget is via the call to:

findAncestorWidgetOfExactType

Of course the problem here is that I don't know the parent's type so that method won't work.

Are there any methods that will allow me to render the tree from my widget back up towards the root of the tree?

The element tree has a method that allows this but I don't know how to access the generated element:

```
List<Element> debugGetDiagnosticChain() {
    final List<Element> chain = <Element>[this];
    Element node = _parent;
    while (node != null) {
      chain.add(node);
      node = node._parent;
    }
    return chain;
  }
```

Comment: This is anti-pattern. There are ways of doing it, but shouldn't. Consider using an InheritedWidget to expose the value, which would make you know the type. Otherwise you may have situations in your app where your UI will be outdated

Comment: I think you have mis-understood the question. I'm not to expose a value simply to provide a debug log message that tells the user that my widget failed and that the copy of my widget failed was the one that is located at location xxx i the tree. Flutter already does this with a number of error messages and they are rather helpful. I've added some notes to the question.

Comment: You can use context.visitAncestorsElement then